# Detect user's payment method for in app purchases on Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app which provides in-app purchases to the user. Everything is working as expected. Now, I wish to know what payment method user has opted to complete the purchases, eg. a credit/debit card / net banking / some coupon redemption etc. I couldn't find anything regarding purchase method in the API docs.
Is there really a way to find what payment method user has used to complete the purchase? I require this information for analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Google Play Support about ability to be know user payment method. They answer that it is not possible now.